# MVC3 Linq updating two tables with data from one model

Tags: database, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

Using the database first approach and Linq, if I have a strongly set fill model for my view, and the following code that passes in an edited fill and updates my fill table in the database, is there a way to update the related rx table as well w/o having to create a viewmodel that has access to fills and rxs?   I'm new to Linq and havent been able to make it work so far.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Fill fill)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Fills.Attach(fill);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(fill, EntityState.Modified);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Rx_ID = new SelectList(db.Rxes, "Rx_ID", "DEA_Number", fill.Rx_ID);
    return View(fill);
}
```

Comment: You should have gone with EF.  And to quote Notorious "No info, for the, DEA Federal agents mad cause I'm flagrant.."

Comment: @DougChamberlain Thanks, not quite sure how Notorious is gonna get me through this but you tried.

Comment: I'm not sure i understand.  What are you trying to update in your rx table?  I don't see any data to update there.

Comment: @MystereMan a fill is related to an rx by the foreign key "Rx_ID", when I update a fill in the fill table I am updating fill.status to "filled" and in the rx table I would like to update the related rx's number of available fills which is in column/property rx.fill

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, and assuming that Fill is a complete object (ie, including it's record id and related navigational id's), and assuming that you have foreign keys and navigational properties, then you should just be able to use the navigational property to do this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Fill fill)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Fills.Attach(fill);
        db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(fill, EntityState.Modified);
        fill.Rx.status = "Filled"; // or whatever the status is
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    ViewBag.Rx_ID = new SelectList(db.Rxes, "Rx_ID", "DEA_Number", fill.Rx_ID);
    return View(fill);
}
```

The above assumes that there is a 1:1 status of fill to Rx, if it's a 1:M than you will have to use some linq to get the proper record you want.